# I have an error when installing the SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, django, installation, pip, speech-recognition

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

I try to install SpeechRecognition with the command above but i get this message:

`from http import cookies`

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cookies' from partially initialized module 'http' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\52644\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py)
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it, in the directory variables I had one that I created that was named PYTHONPATH, you don´t have to do that because python does that automatically, so you would have literally kind of a copy of all the files, that was producing the error. So, i just deleted that variable and it worked. Thanks fo the ones that answered.

Answer (score 0):

While working with a large framework as Django one must always work in a `virtual environment`. Please check if you have your virtual environment activated. If not, then follow the steps:

1. `cd your_working_directory`
2. `virtualenv environment_name` where `environment_name` can be any name you want.
3. `environment_name/Scripts/activate` if on `Windows`

Or `environment_name/bin/activate` if on `MacOS`

Then after activating the environment you can install all the dependencies using pip. i.e `pip install django` or `pip install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: I also tried with a virtual environment but I still have the same error.